# Detection of USB Modem is unstable - how can I correct this?

Tags: usb, modem

I am using Huawei 3G USB Modem in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on DELL Inspiron NS5520. I tried every possible solution but had no luck. Whenever my USB Modem disconnects, I can not re-connect it and then I have to restart laptop. On restart, sometimes it detects the USB Modem and sometimes not. In Ubuntu 11.x It was working fine, but now I am using 12.04. This is the lsusb ouput:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:648d Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's been no other real solution for me other than pull the modem out of the box and then put it back in. Am using `usb-modeswitch` version 1.1.7. This is not difficult, even though it increases wear and tear on the box's USB port.

Comment: While using usb-modeswitch I guess then Network Manager can not be used?

Comment: It can, at least in my case.

Comment: I download and install  usb-modeswitch but it could not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is only a half solution of the problem. Maybe it could help you somewhat on Ubuntu. I am looking for a better solution.

I have the same problem on OpenSuSE 12.1 . Unplugging the modem and plugging it to **a different** USB port helps without a need to restart the system.

Comment: There are commands to reset usb devices with an `ioctl` without unplug

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to diagnose how the modem is detected:

```
udevadm trigger --verbose
```

This won't solve anything but may be a useful first step in your investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restart your network manager instead of your machine.

```
sudo stop network-manager

sudo start network-manager
```

Rarely chances, might be your machine taking your modem as Mass storage device because now-a-days modem come with memory car option, use Modprobe to switch modem.

```
sudo modprobe option
```

Note : (wait for 10 sec your modem will detect)